# What is the secret to keeping breading on chicken when pan frying?

Tags: chicken, frying

Sometimes the coating will stay on pretty well, other times it almost all falls off.  What is the secret to keeping it on?  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Can you describe the process you're currently using to bread and fry your chicken? That will help us troubleshoot ... we aren't a recipe sharing site :)

Comment: It would depend on the recipe, but most of my recipes will call for dipping in an egg/milk wash, then either a flour mix or bread crumb mix, then frying in a small amount of oil or oil/butter mix.  The other night it was just dipped in a beaten egg, then a bread crumb with grated parmesan cheese.  I fried it in oil and butter and about 90% of the topping stuck to the bottom of the frying pan.  This has happened so often and I want to learn how to keep this from happening.